# How can we listen to a specific socket room emit events in flutter? Do suggest a better a solution

Tags: node.js, flutter, socket.io, flutter-dependencies

I am creating a room for every user who connects to socket and emitting separately for those users

For e.g: on server side (Node js) (socket io: 4.7.2)
`io.to(sender_id).emit('newMessage', newMessage); io.to(receiver_id).emit('newMessage', newMessage);`

on the flutter side: (socket io client: 2.0.3+1)
   `socket.on('newMessage', (data) { print('New Message: $data'); });`

I'm able to listen the events but i want to trigger the "on" Event on the flutter side only when there is a message in that specific room

I have tried emitting event with uniqueIds but i don't feel thats a good practice

For e.g: on server side (Node js) (socket io: 4.7.2)

`io.emit('sender_id', newMessage); io.emit('receiver_id', newMessage);`

on the flutter side: (socket io client: 2.0.3+1)

`socket.on('sender_id', (data) { print('New Message: $data'); });`
OR
   `socket.on('receiver_id', (data) { print('New Message: $data'); });`

The versions i'm using are :
for node js server -->>  socket io: 4.7.2
for Flutter -->>  socket io client: 2.0.3+1